Why SonarQube Quality Gate passed despite having more issues?

Am analysing two projects in SonarQube. I am using SonarQube Community Edition with Jenkins pipelines for two projects, and I’ve encountered an issue regarding the quality gate status. Here’s a summary of the issue counts for each project:
Project A:

Bugs: 83
Vulnerabilities: 3
Security Hotspots: 9
Code Smells: 2.6k

Project B:

Bugs: 4
Vulnerabilities: 0
Security Hotspots: 1
Code Smells: 2.6k

Despite Project A having significantly more issues than Project B, its quality gate is passing, while Project B’s quality gate is failing. I expected Project A to have a failed status based on the higher number of issues, but this doesn’t seem to be the case.
Both projects are using different quality gates and quality profiles. Could this be the reason for the difference in the quality gate status?
Additionally, is it possible to adjust the quality gate or quality profile for our own needs as a customised conditions which will enable the quality gate to pass despite having more issue count in it.

Because it depends on the number of line of code of the project.
The quality gate is roughly defined as the ratio (number of bugs) over (number of statements in the code)

And also the quality gate is about the new lines of code, not the overall project.
The idea behind that is that you must use the quality gate to improve your project, but the legacy part is actually legacy, so Sonar focus on the new code

@Codingthermodynamist Is it possible to customize the quality gate/quality profiles to ensure the gate passes?

In what sense customize ? You shouldn't lower the standard to make the quality gate pass, you should actually fix the issues, and as I pointed out, the issues relevant for Sonar are in the new code (the other tab in the screenshot you sent)
